# Homebrew's sbin was not found in your PATH but you have installed formulae that put executables in /usr/local/sbin

Tags: macos, homebrew

when i used `brew doctor` in my mac terminal i get the following output

```
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!

Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
  /usr/local/lib/libtcl8.6.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libtk8.6.dylib

Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected header files:
  /usr/local/include/fakemysql.h
  /usr/local/include/fakepq.h
  /usr/local/include/fakesql.h
  /usr/local/include/itcl.h
  /usr/local/include/itcl2TclOO.h
  /usr/local/include/itclDecls.h
  /usr/local/include/itclInt.h
  /usr/local/include/itclIntDecls.h
  /usr/local/include/itclMigrate2TclCore.h
  /usr/local/include/itclTclIntStubsFcn.h
  /usr/local/include/mysqlStubs.h
  /usr/local/include/odbcStubs.h
  /usr/local/include/pqStubs.h
  /usr/local/include/tcl.h
  /usr/local/include/tclDecls.h
  /usr/local/include/tclOO.h
  /usr/local/include/tclOODecls.h
  /usr/local/include/tclPlatDecls.h
  /usr/local/include/tclThread.h
  /usr/local/include/tclTomMath.h
  /usr/local/include/tclTomMathDecls.h
  /usr/local/include/tdbc.h
  /usr/local/include/tdbcDecls.h
  /usr/local/include/tdbcInt.h
  /usr/local/include/tk.h
  /usr/local/include/tkDecls.h
  /usr/local/include/tkPlatDecls.h

Warning: Unbrewed .pc files were found in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .pc files:
  /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/tcl.pc
  /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/tk.pc

Warning: Unbrewed static libraries were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected static libraries:
  /usr/local/lib/libtclstub8.6.a
  /usr/local/lib/libtkstub8.6.a

Warning: Homebrew's sbin was not found in your PATH but you have installed
formulae that put executables in /usr/local/sbin.
Consider setting the PATH for example like so
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

Warning: Broken symlinks were found. Remove them with `brew prune`:
  /usr/local/bin/2to3-3.6
  /usr/local/bin/easy_install-3.6
  /usr/local/bin/idle3
  /usr/local/bin/idle3.6
  /usr/local/bin/wheel3
  /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/_brew_services
  /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/python-3.6.pc
  /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/python-3.6m.pc
  /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/python3.pc
  /usr/local/share/man/man1/python3.1
  /usr/local/share/man/man1/python3.6.1
  /usr/local/opt/python3
  /usr/local/opt/python@3
  /usr/local/var/homebrew/linked/python3
```

1)so there i see it is asking me to delete some of the files from the folders `/usr/local/lib` `/usr/local/include`  `/usr/local/lib` 
i just want to know how does this files happened to exist and how they effect homebrew.

2)also i did `brew prune` to remove the broken symlinks but i see them again after i again used `brew doctor` .

3) i see a warning above broken symlinks warning i.e

```
Homebrew's sbin was not found in your PATH but you have installed
formulae that put executables in /usr/local/sbin.
Consider setting the PATH for example like so
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

how to fix it?

pardon me if this is being asked again cause i'm a beginner and couldnt find appropriate solutions.

Comment: You appear to have tried at some point to install Tcl/Tk from source or using some other method than **homebrew** and that has created libraries and header files in `/usr/local` that **homebrew** dislikes. Basically you should probably have specified a different install directory when running `configure` for Tcl/Tk. Either leave the files and hope they don't matter, or delete them and when Tcl/Tk next fails, reinstall it but specify  a destination other than `/usr/local`.